# Why Device Code Not Showing as a sign in option in Visual Studio (Tools - Options - Accounts)?

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, msdn

We use Visual Studio in a machine with limited internet access. I use the "Device Code" option to login to my Visual Studio / MSDN subscription from that machine.

In my Tools -> Options -> Accounts screen, I see "Device Code" as an option (VS2019, with all updates). However my coworker, who uses VS2022 Preview (with all updates) doesn't see Device Code as an option. Please see screenshots: [image: Device Code option showing]

[image: Device Code option not showing]

I couldn't see anything in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/accounts-environment-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2022#enable-device-code-flow) about this option being removed. Why is this option not available in VS2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [Microsoft rep](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/enable-device-code-flow-when-adding-or-re-authenti/1660924#T-N1661461), it seems like in Visual Studio 2022 this was deprecated:

> This option is deprecated in Visual Studio 2022.

I *think* the reason it was removed was because of a possible degraded experience.  I can't tell for sure, but version 16.6 (which would be Visual Studio 2019), [changed this I believe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/work-with-multi-factor-authentication?view=vs-2022#how-is-the-visual-studio-experience-affected-by-mfa-policies):

> Versions of Visual Studio prior to 16.6 may have degraded authentication experiences when used with accounts that have enabled CA policies such as MFA, and are associated with two or more tenants.
>
> These issues can cause your instance of Visual Studio to prompt reauthentication multiple times per day. You may have to re-enter your credentials for previously authenticated tenants, even during the course of the same Visual Studio session.